# Linq to EF: find the nearest Nullable Datetime from now

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, nullable

I tried and still confused with calculations of nullable datetime, and the corresponding linq syntax. I am using Linq to EF to find the nearest Task whose StartTime(nullable) is nearest to now. To simplify, please see the demo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime? d0 = null;
    DateTime? d1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
    DateTime? d2 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
    DateTime? d3 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
    DateTime? d4 = null;

    List<DateTime?> dts = new List<DateTime?>() { d0, d1, d2, d3, d4 };

    var v = dts.OrderBy(x => (DateTime.Now - (x)));//runs, but I need Math.Abs, and the nulls are before in order, I want nulls be behind
    //var v = dts.OrderBy(x => (Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - (x)))));//best overloaded: Math.Abs(sbyte)
    //var v = dts.OrderBy(x => (DateTime.Now - (x)).Milliseconds);//TimeSpan? does not contain 'Milliseconds'

    foreach (var x in v)
        Console.WriteLine(x);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am using .net 4.0, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally replaced x with x.Value, and compile error disappeared。

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime? d0 = null;
        DateTime? d1 = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
        DateTime? d2 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
        DateTime? d3 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
        DateTime? d4 = null;

        List<DateTime?> dts = new List<DateTime?>() { d0, d1, d2, d3, d4 };
        //I finally replaced x with x.Value, and compile error disappeared
        var v = dts.Where(x => x.HasValue).OrderBy(x =>
            (Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - x.Value).TotalMilliseconds)));

        foreach (var x in v)
            Console.WriteLine(x);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
var Nearest = dts.Where( d => d != null 
                              && 
                              ( (DateTime.Now - d) > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
                                 || 
                                ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - d)).Negate() > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                              )
                       ).OrderBy(d => d.Value).First();
```

It prints the nearest value to DateTime.Now

Comment: No use because you just did not see my first comments. I need Math.Abs, ie the nearest, neither the first nor the last.

Comment: The second is also wrong, it even filters dates in the future!

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: If all the dates are later than the year 2014, for example 2015, there will also be a nearest one, but your code will get none.

Comment: Finally you OrderBy(d => d.Value)! You went back to starting point!

Comment: Please mark it as an answer, if you think it correct.

Comment: I have tested it different values & results are as expected. I don't know what your problem is, why don't you back your claim with credible facts.

Comment: 2014 should be the result, yours is 2013